# Truffle / Solidity - Can I call mulitple variables, simultaneously?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle

I am currently using Truffle framework to call Etherum block chain (testing with Ganache).

When I call public variables on a contract instance...is it **possible to return multiple variables in one call?**

Example:

Looking to get `started` and `ended` public variables.

My current approach:

```
const started = await instance.started.call({ from: account })
const ended = await instance.ended.call({ from: account })
```

Can I get these 2 variables in one call?

If I am mistaken on the architecture, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method that return a tuple

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract C {
    uint started;
    uint ended;

    // some stuff

    function method() view returns (uint, uint)
    {
        return (started, ended)
    }
}
```